# Deducing the focus of a parabolic mirror

Tags: geometry, conic-sections, quadratics

I've been sitting on it for past three hours but I am unable to spot anything interesting. The first part was obvious but I can't answer the second question (b ii). How can I proof this statement k=a?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of deducing this from the fact that $PQR$ is isosceles is to use $QR=PR$.

The equation of the tangent at $P(at^2,2at)$ is $ty=x+at^2$. Therefore the $x$ coordinate of $Q$ is $-at^2$, and the length $QR=k+at^2$.

Meanwhile, the distance $PR=\sqrt{(at^2-k)^2+4a^2t^2}$

Setting these equal, we have $$(k+at^2)^2=(at^2-k)^2+4a^2t^2$$
$$\Rightarrow k^2+2kat^2+a^2t^4=a^2t^4-2akt^2+k^2+4a^2t^2$$
$$4akt^2=4a^2t^2\rightarrow k=a$$

Comment: Could you please tell me what does the "t" stands for, and if you could also elaborate a little more on the answer that would be great.

Comment: $t$ is the standard parameter value at the point $P$ on the parabola. The standard parametric representation is $x=at^2, y=2at$

Comment: My last question is where does the 4*a^2*t^2 come from? Thank you for your help.

Comment: OK I didn't include the working, but essentially square both sides and multiply out, cancelling terms...do you want me to add this to my answer?

Comment: If you could please add it that you would be very helpful. Thank you once more.

Comment: Ok, know I understand everything. You don't have to edit it. You saved me a lot of time. Thank you for the third time :)

Comment: Pose yourself a question: Find differential equation of reflecting line if all the rays after reflection come to a single focus on x-axis.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write the equation of line $(PR)$. Set $P=(x_0,y_0)$, $\alpha=\alpha_1=\alpha_2$ and observe $\angle\, xRP=2\alpha$.

Now $\tan\alpha$ is the slope of the tangent line to the parabola at $P$. As $\Bigl(\dfrac{y_0}{2a},1\Bigr)$ is a tangent vector to the parabola, we have:
$$\tan\alpha=\frac{2a}{y_0},\enspace\text{hence}
\enspace \tan 2\alpha=\frac{2\tan\alpha}{1-\tan^2\alpha}=\frac{4ay_0}{y_0^2-4a^2}, $$
so that
$$\frac{4ay_0}{y_0^2-4a^2}=\frac{0-y_0}{k-x_0},\enspace\text{whence}\enspace k=\frac{4a^2-y_0^2}{4a}+x_0=a-\frac{y_0^2}{4a}+\frac{y_0^2}{4a}=a.$$